# Fluent assertions event monitoring does not work

Tags: c#, unit-testing, event-handling, nunit, fluent-assertions

I try to using following features for my unit testing
https://fluentassertions.com/eventmonitoring/

But I catch a strange exception on execution line.

```
 Message: 
System.InvalidProgramException : Common Language Runtime detected an invalid program.

 Stack Trace: 
Func`2DynamicHandler(EventRecorder , InternalOrder )
EventExtensions.Raise[T](Func`2 handlers, T arg) line 42
InternalOrderProcessor.CreateInternalOrder(SkuDemand skuDemand, PickLevelDestinationStateInfo pickLevelDestinationStateInfo) line 199
InternalOrderProcessor.CreateInternalOrders(IList`1 skuDemands, PickLevelDestinationStateInfo pickLevelDestinationStateInfo) line 86
InternalOrderProcessorTests.CreateInternalOrder_MultiDemandCoveredWithOneSku_OrderForOneSkuCreatedAndSent()
GenericAdapter`1.GetResult()
AsyncToSyncAdapter.Await(Func`1 invoke)
TestMethodCommand.RunTestMethod(TestExecutionContext context)
TestMethodCommand.Execute(TestExecutionContext context)
<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Execute>b__0()
DelegatingTestCommand.RunTestMethodInThreadAbortSafeZone(TestExecutionContext context, Action action)
```

This is my test code.

```
var monitor = this.service.Monitor();

await this.service.CreateOrder(); // exception here

monitor.Should().Raise(nameof(this.service.OrderCreated));
```

Beside, if I use my solution for check event raised - everything works.

```
var isRaised = false;
this.service.OrderCreated += order =>
{
  isRaised = true;
  return Task.CompletedTask;
};

await this.service.CreateOrder(); // without exception

isRaised.Should().BeTrue();
```

Answer (score 0):

I experience the same problem. After my research I assume, that you are building for a .NET version that is included in [.NET Standard 2.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/standard/net-standard?tabs=net-standard-2-0) like .NET 6.0 or 7.0.

At the bottom of [fluentassertions documentation](https://fluentassertions.com/eventmonitoring/) it is outlined that .NET Standard 2.0 is not supported since there is a specific reflection method missing. So currently there seems to be no better solution than your already implemented way to capture raised events.

Best regards